# Dynamic simple home page builder in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a simple home page website developed in Asp.Net with an admin login through which I can totally change the way the website looks....from header,footer to content.

Does any simple application exist like this already? or should we start developing it?

Thanks.

Comment: There are many CMS out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use asp.net starter kits
. 
http://www.asp.net/community/projects/
It has some CMS like DotnetNuke, umbraco..etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think most of the content management systems have this.  Check out SiteFinity, DotNetNuke, etc.  There are some engines listed on http://www.codeplex.com.   I haven't investigated all of the features to see if they have what you want.

Comment: For the record, Sitefinity is based on standard ASP.NET concepts, so you can use MasterPages, Themes, and UserControls to customize the look/feel and functionality of your site. Also, Sitefinity, DNN, Umbraco, and other .NET CMS platforms are available in the Microsoft Web Platform Installer: http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx